# Should I dispatch an action creator from inside another action

Tags: react-redux

I have a function that set a value in the server and then depending of the result dispatch different actions.

actions.js file:

```
const fetchList = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        return api.list().then(list => {
            dispatch(receiveList(list));
        });
    };
};
```

...

```
const changeItems = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        return api.change()
        .then(() => {
            fetchList()(dispatch);
        })
        .fail(() => {
            messageService('Change Failed')(dispatch);
        });
    };
};
```

Am I doing something wrong or the `fetchList()(dispatch)` is the right thing to do?

Comment: Yes there is nothing wrong with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga).

Comment: Good idea, I'll take a look at it